# Get Total Memory of a host with LINUX/EXPECT

Tags: linux, bash, memory-management, expect

I would like to get the total memory of a host by using a '.exp' script.

After getting inside the host, I execute the following line:

```
"send "top -n 1 | grep Mem: | awk '{ print $(NF-7) }' | cut -d 'k' -f1\r""
```

While executing the script, it returns the following error:

```
 can't read "(NF-7)": no such variable
```

But if get manually inside the host, and execute the same line ( without the "send" part) , it returns me the expected number...

What I'm doing wrong? Any idea? Any proposal for other way of doing the same?

Best Regards and thanks in advance,

Antonio

Comment: `/proc/meminfo` is easier to parse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of `top` is not meant to be parsed this way. You can get the amount of memory in other, easier (better!) ways.

```
sed -n -e '/^MemTotal/s/^[^0-9]*//p' /proc/meminfo
```

Or you can parse the output of `free`, which also knows how to display in convenient sizes:

```
# total memory in megabytes
free -m | sed  -n -e '/^Mem:/s/^[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\) .*/\1/p'
```

EDIT: You always have to ask yourself "Who expands what?"

To send these commands with expect, try

```
send "sed -n -e '/^MemTotal/s/^\[^0-9\]*//p' /proc/meminfo\n"

# also removes kb suffix
send "sed -n -e '/^MemTotal/{s/^\[^0-9\]*//;s/ .*//p}' /proc/meminfo\n"

# displays in megabytes
send "free -m | sed -n -e '/^Mem:/{s/^\[^0-9\]*//;s/ .*//p}'\n"
```

This escapes from `expect` things that it would otherwise process and which were intended for `sed`.

And here's a (properly escaped) version of your original.

```
send "top -n 1 | grep Mem: | awk '{ print \$(NF-7) }' | cut -d 'k' -f1\n"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but it's not fitting completely in my case, with your first solution, it returns the memory size with the letters' kB, adding then at the end ..." | cut -d 'k' -f1" returns what I want, also your second solutions returns the number correctly in the host where I want to know the total memory...but when I introduce it in my '.exp' script it returns me the following error: " invalid command name "^0-9" in both cases...

Comment: @Antonio: I suspect you have quoting issues (this was certainly your original problem).

Answer (score 2):

Expect is a Tcl extension. Tcl will substitute `$variables` in double quoted strings (see the [tutorial chapter](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl3.html))

You want to use braces to send the literal string:

```
send {top -n 1 | grep Mem: | awk '{ print $(NF-7) }' | cut -d 'k' -f1}
send "\r"
```