# How do I extract a certain number from an Expect buffer string?

Tags: expect

I would like to get the total memory of a host by using an Expect script. Thanks to the answers I received in [Get Total Memory of a host with LINUX/EXPECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277503/get-total-memory-of-a-host-with-linux-expect) I am now closer to the final solution. (Thanks to [glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman) and [Sorpigal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180736/sorpigal)).

After connecting to the host, I execute the following line:

```
send "cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal | awk '{print \$2}'\r"
```

It returns the value I want, but when I get the value contained in `$expect_out(buffer)`, it contains much more info than I need, including the send sentences and the previous and posterior command prompt flags. I exactly get the following, using `exp_internal 1`:

```
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "17# cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal | awk '{print $2}'\r\n34150400\r\nCBA"
```

I want to extract just the number near the end, `34150400`. Any hint or idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
regexp "\n(\[0-9]+)" $expect_out(buffer) - num
puts $num   ;# => 34150400
```

By the way, you can do this without sending a shell command:

```
set fid [open /proc/meminfo]
while {[gets $fid line] != -1} {
    if {[regexp {^MemTotal: *(\d+)} $line - memtotal]} {
        break
    }
}
close $fid
puts $memtotal
```